# JSon parsed, how to add a voting system that changes totals Ruby on Rails 5 HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've been able to parse the data and render it in my views as required.  I am trying to add a voting system where people can click yes, and it would change the number of votes.  There was a preset number of yes that were already populated in my parsed data, is there a way to change this?

Here is my views:

```
<% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
      <div class='each'>

        <%= image_tag(roster['image_url'], class: 'image') %>
        <p class='name'> <%= roster['name'] %> </p>
        <p class='title'> <%= roster['title'] %> </p>
        <p> <%= roster['bio'] %> </p>
        <p> <b> Like to see <%= roster['name'] %>? </b> <%= link_to  image_tag 'yes.jpg', class: 'thumbsup' %>
        <br>
        <%= roster['vote'] %> People have said Yes! </p>
        <br>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I want everytime someone clicks on the 'Like to see link_to' link, that it adds 1 to the roster['vote'].  roster['vote'] is data I've parsed from my JSon, different people had prepopulated numbers of yes votes.

roster[vote] is an integer

Comment: Can you show us an example of a value that is in `roster['vote']`?
If it is an integer then I'm pretty sure you could do `roster['vote'] += 1`

Comment: It is an integer in there.  How would I be able to link the link_to to increase the vote?